# Sending a multi-valued attribute in SAML assertion

Tags: connected-apps, single-sign-on, saml, aws, identity-provider

I made connected App in Sandbox to log in AWS using SSO from Salesforce
(SFDC-identity Provider, AWS - ServiceProvider)

we set up NAME ID Format (urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent) with SAML in  Salesforce ConnectedApp Web App Settings

in Connected App we made, i created Apex Custom Connected App Handler to customize customAttriutes
for AWS Role.

it's successful setting single Role , using customAttributes(userId, connectedAppId, formulaDefinedAttributes, context) method
in ConnectedAppPlugin Class.

Here's our Issue now.

i'm trying to add multiple AWS Roles in Role Value but i don't know how send List values of roles in my ConnectedAppPlugin Class(APEX)

AWS official document:
"The IAM role and IAM identity provider are specified as a comma-delimited pair of ARNs in the same format as the RoleArn and PrincipalArn parameters that are passed to AssumeRoleWithSAML. This element must contain at least one role-provider pair (AttributeValue element),
and can contain multiple pairs"
which means i can send multiple roles values from Salesforce
and this is how SAML looks like
Example )
arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/role-name1,arn:aws:iam::account-number:saml-provider/provider-name
arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/role-name2,arn:aws:iam::account-number:saml-provider/provider-name
arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/role-name3,arn:aws:iam::account-number:saml-provider/provider-name

this is part of my Custom Connected App Handler code >>>>

```
  global override Map customAttributes(Id userId, Id connectedAppId, MapformulaDefinedAttributes, Auth.InvocationContext context){
    
    formulaDefinedAttributes.put('https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName', userInfo.getLastName());
    formulaDefinedAttributes.put('https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role',
    'arn:aws:iam::***********:role/role1' +','+ arn:aws:iam::**********:saml-provider/Salesforce );
    }
```

and this is working as a single role value.

but in Role value, i need add multiple aws role arn & identity Provider ARN pairs and i don't know how ..

this is code i tried and AWS responsed 'Your request included an invalid SAML response'

---

formulaDefinedAttributes.put('https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role',
'[{'+stringROLE1ARN+','+idpARN+'},'+'{'+stringROLE2ARN+','+idpARN+'}]');

formulaDefinedAttributes.put('https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role'',
'['+idpARN + ',' + stringROLE1ARN + ';' +idpARN+','+ stringROLE2ARN+';]');

formulaDefinedAttributes.put('https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role'',
stringROLE1ARN + ',' + idpARN + ',' + stringROLE2ARN + ',' + idpARN );

---

how can i send these multiple role values in SAML to AWS and aws user from Salesforce can have multiple roles in AWS IAM ?
it will be so helpful if there's code example.
thank you

Comment: This is known as a multi-valued attribute in SAML. `customAttributes` method does not support multi-valued attributes but a lower-level approach via [`modifySAMLResponse`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm#apex_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin_modifySAMLResponse) _might_ work. Give it a shot.

Comment: If your goal is SSO to AWS console, you can try calling [GetFederationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetFederationToken.html) via [AWS STS  + AWS SIgV4](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_awssig4_ext_cred.htm&type=5) auth model supported in Named Credential, then using the resulting token for access to console.

Comment: @identigral 
i switched over to modySAMLResponse method and add AttributeValue Element and now it works !!! Thank you sooo much